# Les articles indéfinis

Tags: grammaire

Est ce que la phrase suivante est correcte `Frédéric et Thomas sont des enfants` ?

Vu que dans cette phrase les enfants sont bien connus doit-je utiliser `les enfants` au lieu de `des enfants` ?

Ou encore: Alain est un garçon. 
Dans cette phrase on parle d'une personne définie. Pourquoi un article indéfini est utilisé?

Comment: In English, do you say "Alain is *a* boy" or "Alain is *the* boy" ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I am not an english native speaker.

Comment: Once again, it depends on the context.

Comment: Ceci n'est pas vraiment une question de français mais plutôt de linguistique, il s'agit des  définitions de « défini » et « indéfini » qui sont communes à  plusieurs langues.

Comment: F. et T. sont des garcons [et pas des filles]. Ils ***appartiennent à la catégorie garçons*** et pas à la catégorie filles.  F. et T. sont les garcons [qui ont joué dans le jardin]. Ils sont les garçons spécifiques d'un contexte spécifique. F. and T. are boys [no article in English]; F. and T. are the boys [the ones who played in the garden].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans la phrase :

> Alain est un garçon.

le nom « garçon » est indéfini, il pris dans son sens générique (Alain est un garçon et pas une fille).

Dans la phrase :

> Alain est le garçon qui a un pull bleu.

le nom « garçon » est défini, on ne parle pas de n'importe quel garçon mais du seul garçon qui répond à la caractéristique « porter un pull bleu ».

Dans la phrase :

> Frédéric et Thomas sont des enfants.

le mot « enfants » n'est pas défini, il est pris au sens générique, ce sont des enfants et pas des adultes.

Dans la phrase :

> Frédéric et Thomas sont des enfants sages.

le mot « enfants » est défini par la caractéristique d'être « sages ».

Ce sont les notions de « défini » et « indéfini » qui sont à comprendre ici, on les retrouve dans beaucoup de langues et ce n'est pas spécifique au français.

Comment: Est-ce que vous voulez dire Frédéric et Thomas sont **les** enfants sages?

Comment: @Koks_rs On ne peut pas dire tout seul « Frédéric et Thomas sont les enfants sages », pour employer « les » il faudrait définir « enfants sages », par exemple : « Frédéric et Thomas sont les enfants sages dont je vous ai parlé.  »

Answer (score 3):

We need more context to decide. Both are possible. We could say:

> Frédéric et Thomas sont des enfants qui vivent à la campagne.

and

> Frédéric et Thomas sont les enfants de Marie.

Maybe closer to your initial example:

> Voici la famille Durand. Frédéric et Thomas sont les enfants. Pierre et Marie sont les parents. (sound weird though)

With an indefinite article:

> Alain est un garçon.

but with the definite article:

> Alain est le garçon de la famille.